# Softening the corners of the grid without adding polygons

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I am creating a landscape, and in order for the game engine to apply its smoothing, I need the height difference of the points not to exceed 25 degrees.

I want to see the difference in the height difference to fix the sharp edges.
If possible, then in the modeling mode too.

And if there was a possibility of automatic correction of points, it would be generally ideal, while I cannot increase the number of polygons, which means that the separation surface modifier does not suit me.

I found a grid analysis, but as far as I understand, it displays angles, and when the model is triangulated, planes without differences are highlighted in red. In general, this is not the effect I wanted to achieve.
[image: Text]